# How to center background text of image

Tags: html, css, background

The title pretty much says it, I have a image which has a text on it. And I would like to keep it always centered, both horizontally and vertically. Now I am doing it with

```
headerText: {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 5%;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work for different resolutions. So is there other way how to achieve this layout?

[Link](http://stavarov-ubytovna.cz/index.html) to the website (yellow header is the text I want to center)

Comment: can you try vertical-align: middle; inside your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to add the following CSS to the .headerText style:

```
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This one + top 35% did it:)Thank

Answer (score 1):

Just move the span before the image tags, like so:

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="headerText">Ubytovna Stavařov Přerov</span>´
    <img src="css/title578145459.png" class="headerImage left">
    <img src="css/title756941752.png" class="headerImage right">            
</div>
```

and you header text css needs to be

```
.headerText {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: yellow;
    font: bolder 6em justus;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

That should make it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the text in a div or span then you can easily align them to be centered. With the dig, all you meed is

```
margin: auto
```

Comment: or rather "a group of stars forming a recognizable pattern"

Comment: XD sorry for that. what i meant is, that `margin: auto` doesn't work with the way Petr Mensik wrote his markup.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
headerText: {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 5%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: the colon after `headerText` should be removed.
Second: I assume `headerText` is a class selector, so you have to prepend a `.` to `headerText`

I would recommend to set the image as `background-image`. Then you can do the following
Then:

```
.headerText {
    background-image: url(path/to/your/image.png)
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But it depends on whether your image has to be part of the page's content or it is design/style only. This solution makes sense only in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix for vertically centered.

```
.headerText{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  line-height:190px;
}
```

Make sure you modify the height for different resolutions, depending on where the header words wrap - looks pretty bad with massive line-height, wrapped.

Horizontally centered is pretty quick too:

```
.headerText{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

All together now:

```
.headerText{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  line-height:190px;
  text-align:center;
}
```